# How to connect an external device through wifi in iOS?

Tags: ios, gamekit, mfi

I have an external device which transmits some data through wifi. In my iPhone app i want to collect the data from that device and also, i want to **transmit some data to that external device from my app**. I am not sure whether this is possible or not. Can someone tell, how i can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

iOS supports bonjour, you can use it to connect to network services. I recommend checking out this page Apple has, that should give you a good start:

https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/